# command sort -h does not return a reasonable result

Tags: ls, sort

I tried to sort files using `sort -h`

```
algorithms@algorithms:~$ ls -lh /boot | sort -h
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4.0K Dec 28 16:19 grub
-rw------- 1 root root 4.2M Dec  5 13:10 System.map-4.18.0-13-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 4.2M Nov 14 21:30 System.map-4.18.0-12-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 8.2M Dec  5 13:11 vmlinuz-4.18.0-13-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 8.2M Nov 14 21:50 vmlinuz-4.18.0-12-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.5M Nov 14 21:30 abi-4.18.0-12-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 179K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   17 Nov 14 21:30 retpoline-4.18.0-12-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 181K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 181K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 212K Dec  5 13:10 config-4.18.0-13-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 212K Nov 14 21:30 config-4.18.0-12-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  38M Dec 18 15:47 initrd.img-4.18.0-12-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  38M Dec 28 16:25 initrd.img-4.18.0-13-generic
```

However, it does not sort reasonably.

Reference to the manual:

```
   -h, --human-numeric-sort
          compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)
```

What's the problem with my usage?

Comment: @roaima OP wants to know how to use of `h` option in sort.

Comment: Unclear: It is unknown what you mean by "reasonably".

Comment: @P_Yadav it looks like an XY problem. There's little point solving Y if X is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your question, you have to provide the column number also i.e.

```
ls -lh /boot | sort -hk5
```

Now it will sort the output based upon the column 5 i.e. column which represents size.

Here the use of `h` is, if you use the command `ls -lh /boot | sort -nk5`, then it will sort according to the numbers without considering `K,M,G`, and if you use `h` option, then it will consider `K,M,G`.

If you want to sort then better option is `ls -lhS /boot`as suggested by roaima.

Comment: But `ls -lhS /boot` will avoid the need to pipe into `sort` at all